# azure cannot pass contact information validation when buying domain

Tags: azure, domain-name

I am trying to buy a domain on Microsoft Azure.
But no matter what I enter I cannot pass the validation when entering contact information.
I am pretty sure the info is correct, no mistakes, no typos, it just says "Validation failed. Please double check your contact information" (it's pretty stupid it doesn't actually tell you, what is wrong!!).
Can anyone experienced help me, please? I could PM print screen with the info I filled.
Thank you very much, it's driving me crazy :-)

Comment: Which screen you are talking about? At the time of buying subscription?

Comment: No, screen with the filled contact information :-)
Because I cannot figure out which one is missing.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for taking interest but it works now, I tried again after some time and I entered the same info as before and it went through.
Thanks